# iOS app crashes on a specific question in Movies & TV

Tags: bug, specific-question, ios-app

In the Hot Questions feed right now is a question titled [What cameos has Stan Lee had?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73806/what-cameos-has-stan-lee-had).

Tapping on this question displays the post and then the app crashes about 4 seconds later.  Happens for me consistently on this one question.

Comment: Probably due to the many YouTube embeds, though it does not crash the android app.

Comment: My PC barely survives that answer, heh. It's ~41 mb over ~600 requests with a load time of ~59 seconds. It's pretty hefty although yeah, the app shouldn't crash, unless perhaps the device is out of memory.

Comment: No repro here, what app version and device are you using?

Comment: @Cai repro for 1.6.6.2 iPad

Comment: @alexolut yeh, just checked, I can repro on iPad mini but not on iPhone 6 (both 1.6.6.2)

Comment: This looks like is was an OOM problem.  I'm not seeing any related crashes from that time so memory-use is the likely culprit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** All embedded videos have been changed to hyperlinks. Post should no longer crash on mobile.

---

Author of the aformentioned post here. I should probably apologize about that...

My self-answer on that post is a lengthy behemoth, containing over 100 hyperlinked references and around 34 embedded YouTube videos.

[As Jason C remarked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296500/ios-app-crashes-on-a-specific-question-in-movies-tv#comment962017_296500):

> My PC barely survives that answer, heh. It's ~41 mb over ~600 requests
>   with a load time of ~59 seconds. It's pretty hefty although yeah, the
>   app shouldn't crash, unless perhaps the device is out of memory.

In the [Movies & TV chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37704543#37704543), it's been suggested that the videos be changed to hyperlinks instead of embedded videos to alleviate the issue. It's a good idea, since loading 34 videos at once is fairly demanding on any machine. <s>I just haven't had the chance to sit down and convert every single link.</s>

Funnily enough, you actually beat me to the punch on reporting this. I was planning on asking my own version of this question with the title "How many YouTube videos does it take to crash Stack Exchange?"

Comment: Just whatever you do, don't look at the revision history; it's that * 11, ha.

Comment: @Jason maybe better redact the previous revisions...